# What faster "Insert ignore" or "Select and Insert"

Tags: php, mysql, performance

mysql database.

Table have index on field "Code".
I need to insert to table new rows.
What works faster?

1)

- simple index on field Code - for fast select
- befor insert check rows : `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE Code = 'NewCode';`
- simple insert(if rows not found): `Insert into table values ('NewCode')`

2)

- unique index on field Code - for insert
- `Insert IGNORE into table values ('NewCode')`

Comment: The former doesn't always work. Hint: concurrent updates.

Comment: I've always liked MySQL's [`ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE/IGNORE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).  As for what is faster.  Run it in a loop, time it, and see.

Answer (score 0):

For me more secure (and can be a backup of changes - better way) is the first, but I think that the action is similar.
Consult http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html for more detali

paladinux